# Is the relationship from a Slide Part to a Custom XML Part not an explicit relationship instead of an implicit?

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, openxml

If I want to associate a **Custom XML Part** to a **Slide Part**, the way I know of, is to add a `custData` element inside the Slide Part, and reference the *relationship id* of the Custom XML Part in the `id` attribute.

```
<p:custDataLst>
  <p:custData r:id="rId1" />
</p:custDataLst>
```

As I understand it, this is an *explicit* relationship, because the reference is via the relationship id.

However, [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/flat/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) Part 1, fifth edition (Latest version currently), says that a **Slide Part** is only permitted to have an *implicit* relationship to a **Custom XML Part** (Section 13.3.8).

That doesn't really make sense to me. In practice, I see an explicit relationship, while the specification only allows for an implicit one.

This is also how PowerPoint do it if I use the VSTO object model. If I create a completely fresh VSTO project, and edit the startup method to be like this:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.AfterNewPresentation += pres =>
    {
        var firstSlide = pres.Slides[1];
        var customXmlPart = firstSlide.CustomerData.Add();
        customXmlPart.LoadXML("<test></test>");
    };
}
```

Then save the presentation and look at the package structure, PowerPoint did the exact same thing: Added a `custData` element to the slide, referencing the custom XML part using the relationship id. I.e. an *explicit* relationship.

I'm confident that the specification is correct, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turns out that Office knowingly doesn't follow the specification to the letter. Luckily, Microsoft actually documents where they diverge from the standard. This documentation can be found at the [Open Specifications website on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecifications/). Diving into the documentation here, I found the page [Word, Excel, and PowerPoint Standards Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d5784a8b-7070-466b-befa-b7bf3724c6f0), which has quite a few PDF documents that documents how the standard is implemented in Word, PowerPoint and Excel. Diving further into [[MS-OE376]: Office Implementation Information for ECMA-376 Standards Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ee908654), section 2.1.23.e states:

> *The standard states that the Presentation part is permitted to have an implicit relationship to a Custom XML Data Storage part.*
>
> Office also allows for an explicit relationship between the Presentation part and a Custom XML Data Storage part.

The PDF document doesn't say anything about this for slides, but now I'm no longer unsure if I was interpreting the standard incorrectly or if PowerPoint just didn't follow the standard. It's pretty clear that PowerPoint in a lot of cases doesn't follow the standard, so the specific case I have with an explicit relationship between a **Slide Part** and a **Custom XML Data Storage Part** is probably just another case where PowerPoint doesn't follow the standard.